# How to share behavior b/w classes in python?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Like in ruby we have module which can be included in any given class and then we can use the methods defined there, this saves us from inheritance which is considered as a coupling. In python is there any way to replicate same functionality? For eg I have two classes

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass
```

I want to have both of the above two classes to have logging functionality which may be like:

```
def log(message):
    print message
```

Comment: You can just as well put behavior in a separate module and use it wherever you need it in Python. But I don't see what you'd gain from that and how that would reduce coupling.

Comment: I don't understand why you want avoid inheritance when you actually want to mixin methods :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, we generally just go ahead and use inheritance for this. It's essentially a mixin pattern.

You *can* use modules, though, if you really want to:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    from methods import baz, bar, quux
```

Here `methods.py` would be a module containing functions (or other attributes) named `baz`, `bar`, and `quux`, and possibly others. As shown, you can go ahead and define methods directly on the class as well.

Using a wildcard import gives you a warning in Python 2.7 and I believe it's disallowed entirely in Python 3.x:

```
class Foo(object):
    from methods import *
```

So, as usual in Python, "explicit is better than implicit." That is, specify exactly which methods you want in your class instead of saying "give me all of them." It makes your code much clearer.

Comment: +1 It makes the code clearer *and* potentially easier to debug as `import *` may conflict with a previous `import *`

Comment: Yes, or it may even overwrite a definition you made directly on the class!

Comment: Marked as accepted because it gives some new insights on the use of modules. Thanks!